# launchd - how to get name of file changed

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, launchd

I want to use launchd to kick off a script to backup changed files.  It looks like it should work for what I want to do, but I don't know how to pass to my script that launchd starts, the  path of the updated file.  So if I'm watching directory foo and file bar.txt is changed, how do I get my launchd.plist or the script it runs to get the value of bar.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any way to do it with launchd. Could you just use rsync or something? Or check the modification dates in the script, by for example using find if it's a shell script:

```
find /some/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime -20s
```

Folder actions do get pathnames as an argument, but they are only run when files are added to a folder and not when files are modified. You can create a folder action by using the folder action template in Automator, or by saving a script like the one below in `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/` and then enabling the script from Folder Actions Setup.

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    say POSIX path of item 1 of these_items
end
```